# Varying width in different simulators when used self.frame.width

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

when I have used the constraints for the border of the textfield which is placed in a table view, the width of the textfield is differing from one simulator to another simulator

The constraints I have used was

```
textField.frame = CGRect(x: 18, y: self.frame.height/2, width: self.frame.width+50, height: 28)
```

In iPhone8 it is showing up like  [image of the textfield in iphone8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0Gcp.png)

In iPhone8Plus it is showing up like [image of the textfield in iPhone8Plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCNgm.png)

why is it so? What exactly does frame.width refers to?

Comment: Where is this line of code? What is `self` referring to?

Comment: We we use the word "constraints", it's suggest NSLayoutConstraint, which you aren't using. Possibly, `didLayoutSubview()` hasn't be called yet, so `self.frame.width` isn't the "final" on yet, which could explain your behavior.

Comment: I think Larme is on the right track with the issue of didLayoutSubview(). If this code is running in viewDidLoad, the result will be different than if you are adding this textField to a view that has already been displayed. Can you post more of the code?